# What will be the time complexity of such kind of functions?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, time-complexity

```
void yash(){ 

    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       for(j=1;j<=log(i);j++)
          printf("Hello !!");
}
```

what will be the complexity of this function?

Comment: O Time complexity?

Comment: Yeah O time complexity

Comment: In terms of big O annotation, O(n*log(n))

Comment: What do **YOU** think? Share your thoughts!

Comment: Depends on how costly the `log(i)`-call is.

Answer (score 2):

Loop will iterate like this-

- `1` * `log(1)` time.
- `2` * `log(2)` times.
- so on and so forth till `n * log(n)` times.

Among all these values, `n * log(n)` is the highest(upper bound). So, time complexity is `n * log(n)` asymptotically.

**UPDATE:**

If you are calculating `log(i)` for each iteration instead of storing it in a variable, then time complexity is **O(n * log(n) <sup>2</sup>)**, assuming calculating log(i) isn't O(1). If it's O(1), then time complexity is O(n  log(n)).

Comment: "assuming calculating log(i) isn't O(1)" What time complexity could log(i) have that would make the term log(n)^2? O(log n)?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, but not sure. Hence, I said `assuming`.